# How to use a CheckBox in Xamarin.forms?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, checkbox, xamarin.forms

I'm new in Xamarin.forms and I'm trying to use a multiple CheckBox that I create from a list.

I understand that CheckBox Doesn't exist in Xamarin.forms so I created a class that I finded on Internet to create the control.

When I try to create the CheckBox I can't see it. This is the code when I create the CheckBox:

```
if (List1 != null && List1.Count > 0)
{
    foreach (var c in List1)
    {
        CheckBox chk = new CheckBox();
        chk.CheckedChanged += Chk_CheckedChanged;
        chk.IsVisible = true;
        chk.CheckBoxBackgroundColor = Color.Blue;
        chk.TickColor = Color.Blue;
        chk.WidthRequest = 12;
        chk.HeightRequest = 12;
        StackLayoutBody.Children.Add(chk);
    }
}
```

And this is the code of the CheckBox.cs:

```
using System;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace TECAndroid.Services
{
    public class CheckBox : View
    {
        public static readonly BindableProperty CheckedProperty =
            BindableProperty.Create(nameof(Checked), typeof(bool), typeof(CheckBox), false, BindingMode.TwoWay,
                propertyChanged: (bindable, oldValue, newValue) =>
                {
                    ((CheckBox)bindable).CheckedChanged?.Invoke(bindable, new CheckedChangedEventArgs((bool)newValue));
                });


        public static readonly BindableProperty TickColorProperty =
            BindableProperty.Create(nameof(TickColor), typeof(Color), ypeof(CheckBox), Color.Default, BindingMode.TwoWay);

        public static readonly BindableProperty CheckBoxBackgroundColorProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(CheckBoxBackgroundColor), typeof(Color), typeof(CheckBox), Color.Default, BindingMode.TwoWay);

        public EventHandler<CheckedChangedEventArgs> CheckedChanged;

        public Color TickColor
        {
            get => (Color)GetValue(TickColorProperty);
            set => SetValue(TickColorProperty, value);
        }

        public Color CheckBoxBackgroundColor
        {
            get => (Color)GetValue(CheckBoxBackgroundColorProperty);
            set => SetValue(CheckBoxBackgroundColorProperty, value);
        }

        public bool Checked
        {
            get => (bool)GetValue(CheckedProperty);
            set
            {
                if (Checked != value) SetValue(CheckedProperty, value);
            }
        }
    }

    public class CheckedChangedEventArgs : EventArgs
    {
        public CheckedChangedEventArgs(bool value)
        {
            Checked = value;
        }

        public bool Checked { get; }
    }
}
```

Can anyone help me please?!

Comment: Posting the original class that you found online would help

Comment: And the Xaml aswell

Comment: This class doesn't implement the UI of the checkbox. It's just a Xamarin.Forms class to create native Renderers with it. Usually I use a Switch when I need a Checkbox, but if a Switch is not good enough you either will have to look for the native renderers implementation on each platform or look for a cross-platform implementation using Xamarin.Forms' views.

Comment: I was looking for examples of the switch and finally it will be the most convenient to use. I had a wrong idea of how it works, I thought it would be something like toogle. Thanks to everyone for the comments!

Comment: Now I have another quetion, the sentence StackLayoutBody.Children.Add(chk); doesn't work because chk (Now is a SwitchCell instead a CheckBox) must be a Xamarin.forms.View... how can I add it?

Comment: I'll add an answer so this question can be closed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This class doesn't implement the UI of the checkbox. It's just a Xamarin.Forms class to create native Renderers with it. Usually I use a Switch when I need a Checkbox, but if a Switch is not good enough you either will have to look for the native renderers implementation on each platform or look for a cross-platform implementation using Xamarin.Forms' views.

And for your other question, the control you want is not a `SwitchCell`, is simply a `Switch`. If you want, here's the link to the documentation with examples: [Switch Documentation](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Xamarin.Forms.Switch/).